# The app doesn't connect to the server on Android

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, hybrid-mobile-app

I have Meteor project that works fine when testing it on the browser (chrome, and safari), it also work as expected on IOS (both simulator and real device) with the following command `meteor run ios-device`.

However, when I try to test the application on android using `meteor run android-device`, the application runs in my Android real device but it doesn't seem to connect to the server, and when I try to use a function that requires server connectivity such as registering, I get the following error printed to the console (`using chrome DevTools`):

[image: Error in the console]

The above error only occurs when trying to test the application on android simulator or android real device.

Any feedback on what might be causing the issue?

Comment: Did you try a browser on your Android device.

Comment: If you google for clear text you get the solution in seconds.

Comment: @blackapps yea I found it, came here to post the solution, newb error, sorry

Comment: Came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57980657/meteor-cordova-android-app-not-connecting-to-server-if-server-is-running-on-vmwa) that solved my issue.